# Why is "Verify apps over USB" grayed-out in Settings > Dev Options?

Tags: android, android-settings

I'm using Android 5.0 on a new phone of mine. I'm trying to disable **Verify Apps over USB** (under **Settings > Developer Options**); I've enabled the developer options in general, but this particular setting remains grayed out. Why? And how can I disable it?

Answer (score 7):

Use below command to turn off 'Verify apps over USB'

```
adb shell settings put global verifier_verify_adb_installs 0
```

Use below command to turn on 'Verify apps over USB'

```
adb shell settings put global verifier_verify_adb_installs 1
```

To get values, use below command

```
adb shell settings get global verifier_verify_adb_installs
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Btw. if someone is having issues with permissions, just open regular `adb shell`, and then enter `su`, and then just a part after `adb shell` from the above commands.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work on Pelton bike. https://www.reddit.com/r/pelotoncycle/comments/nzd3b7/pelton_adb_install_packagemanager_keys_mismatch. Stilled grayed out https://imgur.com/a/AaYQEYu

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Settings** > **Security** > Check **Verify Apps** to enable it then go back and uncheck **Verify apps via USB**..
Then after its done don't forget to again uncheck in **Settings** > **Security** > **Verify Apps**

Comment: I don't have a **Settings > Security > Verify Apps** option.

Comment: make sure you have **usb debugging** enabled in developer options

Comment: In developer options, disable and re-enable developer mode (off/on)  in top.

Comment: Do you mean the option in "Settings > Security" next to "Unknown sources"? If so, can you edit that into the question?

Answer (score 0):

In the developer Options -

Mi Unlock Status > Add account & device.

Then enable Install via USB.

Comment: Where are these Developer Options which have a "Mi Unlock Status"?

Answer (score 0):

On galaxy s7 with Android 7,developer option enabled but 90 % greyed out. Had to enable OEM unlock.Then I could turn on usb debug .